# How to unload a custom user control programatically in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I want to unload a user control on the click of a button inside the user control. I am calling this user control inside navigation:page for the filtering the rad gridview.

I think Making the visibility collapsed wont unload it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from visualtree. Suppose that your control "myControl" is contained within Panel derivate called "LayoutRoot" then you can do this:

LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(myControl).